# Retrieve service information from WFS GetCapabilities request with GeoExt

Tags: web-services, extjs

This is probably a very simple question but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I am writing a Javascript app to retrieve layer information from a WFS server using a GetCapabilities request using GeoExt.  GetCapabilities returns information about the WFS server -- the server's name, who runs it, etc., in addition to information on the data layers it has on offer.

My basic code looks like this:

```
var store = new GeoExt.data.WFSCapabilitiesStore({ url: serverURL });

store.on('load', successFunction);
store.on('exception', failureFunction);
store.load();
```

This works as expected, and when the loading completes, successFunction is called.

successFunction looks like this:

```
successFunction = function(dataProxy, records, options) { 
   doSomeStuff();
}
```

dataProxy is a Ext.data.DataProxy object, records is a list of records, one for each layer on the WFS server, and options is empty.

And here is where I'm stuck: In this function, I can get access to all the layer information regarding data offered by the server.  But I also want to extract the server information that is contained in the XML fetched during the store.load() (see below).  But I can't figure out how to get it out of the dataProxy object, where I'm sure it must be squirreled away.

Any ideas?

---

The fields I want are contained in this snippet:

```
<ows:ServiceIdentification>
  <ows:Title>G_WIS_testIvago</ows:Title>
  <ows:Abstract/>
  <ows:Keywords>
     <ows:Keyword/>
  </ows:Keywords>
  <ows:ServiceType>WFS</ows:ServiceType>
  <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.1.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
  <ows:Fees/>
  <ows:AccessConstraints/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently,GeoExt currently discards the server information, undermining the entire premise of my question.

Here is a code snippet that can be used to tell GeoExt to grab it.  I did not write this code, but have tested it, and found it works well for me:

https://github.com/opengeo/gxp/blob/master/src/script/plugins/WMSSource.js#L37